# Negative glob in Makefile recipe syntax error

Tags: makefile, syntax-error, gnu-make, glob

If I run the following command directly in /bin/bash it executes perfectly:

```
cp test_!(*.o) ./tmp/
```

(I just want to copy all files but objects)

Anyway if I put this command inside a Makefile recipe it gives

```
bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Example of Makefile

```
all:
        cp test_!(*.o) ./tmp/
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: `!(*.o)` is an [*extended* pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) feature, turned on with `shopt -s extglob`. It may not be available in the subshells spawned by the Makefile, though there's likely a way to turn it on. Sorry, I don't use Makefile much these days, and never needed this, so can't tell you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your glob:

```
test_!(*.o)
```

employs extended globbing syntax.

Look at this:

```
$ shopt | grep extglob
extglob         on
```

And then at:

```
$ cat Makefile
SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    shopt | grep extglob

$ make
shopt | grep extglob
extglob         off
```

Invoked in the terminal, `bash` is in interactive mode (as per `bash -i`), and
shell opt `extglob` is `on`.

Invoked by `make`, `bash` is not in interactive mode (as per `bash -c <command>`),
and shell opt `extglob` is `off`.

You can make your recipe command work by enabling `extglob` in the
[`.SHELLFLAGS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)
of your makefile, e.g.

```
$ cat Makefile
SHELL := /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS := -O extglob -c

all:
    cp test_!(*.o) ./tmp/

$ make
cp test_!(*.o) ./tmp/
cp: cannot stat 'test_!(*.o)': No such file or directory
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

As you see, no matches in my working directory, but no syntax error.